# Unable to view data on an oservable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, knockout.js

I have a View model, which has a loaddata function. It has no constructor. I want it to call the loadData method IF the ID field has a value.

That field is obtained via:

```
self.TemplateId = ko.observable($("#InputTemplateId").val());
```

Then, at the end of my ViewModel, I have a bit of code that checks that, and calls my load function:

```
if (!self.CreateMode()) {
        self.loadData();
    }
```

My load method makes a call to my .Net WebAPI method, which returns a slighly complex structure. The structure is a class, with a few fields, and an Array/List. The items in that list, are a few basic fields, and another List/Array. And then THAT object just has a few fields. So, it's 3 levels. An object, with a List of objects, and those objects each have another list of objects...

My WebAPI call is working. I've debugged it, and the data is coming back perfectly.

```
self.loadData = function () {
        $.get("/api/PlateTemplate/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
            self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));

        });
    }
```

I am trying to load the contents of this call, into an observable object called 'Data'. It was declared earlier:

```
self.Data = ko.observable();
```

TO load it, and keep everything observable, I am using the Knockout mapping plugin.

```
self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
```

When I breakpoint on that, I am seeing what I expect in both data (the result of the API call), and self.Data()

[image]

self.Data seems to be an observable version of the data that I loaded. All data is there, and it all seems to be right.

I am able to alert the value of one of the fields in the root of the data object:

```
alert(self.Data().Description());
```

I'm also able to see a field within the first item in the list.

```
alert(self.Data().PlateTemplateGroups()[0].Description());
```

This indicates to me that Data is an observable and contains the data. I think I will later be able to post self.Data back to my API to save/update.

Now, the problems start.

On my View, I am trying to show a field which resides in the root class of my complex item. Something I alerted just above.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Template Name" data-bind="value: Data.Description">
```

I get no error. Yet, the text box is empty.

If I change the code for the input box to be:

```
data-bind="value: Data().Description()"
```

Data is displayed. However, I am sitting with an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function
>   (){return Data().Description() }" Message: Cannot read property
>   'Description' of undefined

I think it's due to the view loading, before the data is loaded from the WebAPI call, and therefore, because I am using ko.mapping - the view has no idea what Data().Description() is... and it dies.

Is there a way around this so that I can achieve what I am trying to do? Below is the full ViewModel.

```
function PlateTemplateViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.TemplateId = ko.observable($("#InputTemplateId").val());
    self.CreateMode = ko.observable(!!self.TemplateId() == false);

    self.IsComponentEditMode = ko.observable(false);
    self.IsDisplayMode = ko.observable(true);
    self.CurrentComponent = ko.observable();

    self.Data = ko.observable();

    self.EditComponent = function (data) {

        self.IsComponentEditMode(true);
        self.IsDisplayMode(false);
        self.CurrentComponent(data);

    }
    self.loadData = function () {
        $.get("/api/PlateTemplate/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
            self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));

        });
    }

    self.cancel = function () {
        window.location.href = "/PlateTemplate/";
    };

    self.save = function () {
        var data = ko.mapping.toJS(self.Data);
        $.post("/api/PlateTemplate/Save", data).done(function (result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    };

    if (!self.CreateMode()) {
        self.loadData();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new PlateTemplateViewModel(), $("#plateTemplate")[0]);
});
```

Maybe the answer is to do the load inside the ready() function, and pass in data as a parameter? Not sure what happens when I want to create a New item, but I can get to that.

Additionally, when I try save, I notice that even though I might change a field in the view (Update Description, for example), the data in the observed view model (self.Data) doesn't change.

Comment: By `Data.Description` you want to point to the `Data` property in your *root* view model or to the `Data` in *each* of your `PlateTemplateGroups`? In other words, where exactly (at what scope) does this `data-bind=...` resides? Also, have you tried `value: Data() && Data().Description && Data().Description()`?

Comment: You could try this:  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Data);  (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html, 'Specifying the update target').

Comment: @JoseLuis - I tried that, and I had to remove the brackets from all my bind objects. And no data appears on the view. Although this.Data has data. It seems the screen is maybe binding too early?

Comment: @haim770 - What is happening is that my View is rendering based on this.Data (The object that is populated with data). However, when I change a value in an edit box, and then post back "this.Data" to my controller - the original values are in this.Data - not the new values that I entered. It seems although the view renders with the data from Data().Description() - when I change the Description - and then post this.Data back - Data.Description contains the original value from when I loaded the data from the controller. Not the updated data I changed in the view.

Comment: When I use self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)); , In my view, I reference data like this: Data().Description(). But if I use ko.mapping.fromJS(self.Data, {}, data) (But no data appears). What is the correct way?

Comment: @Craig If `Description` is an observable:  `data-bind="value: Data().Description"`  (`Description` without parentheses).  You can also use the `with` binding.  Example:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwdYBL

Comment: it is not  `ko.mapping.fromJS(self.Data, {}, data)` but `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Data)`.

Comment: Thanks @JoseLuis - I tried both to be sure. When I try this, I get an error on the first field that tries to bind on my view: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return Data().Description() }" .... When I remove the (), the edit box is empty. Before, it had data from this.Data(). So I am not sure which way is right and why I get no data.

Comment: @Craig In this CodePen:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqJQqJ, if you click in 'Load Data', data gets updated.  With `ko.mapping.fromJS(parsed, {}, self.Data);` works ok.

Comment: @JoseLuis - In your CodePen example (Thank you, by the way), you have created a class outside of the view model called 'Data'. I don't have that. In it, you specify 'Description'. Do I need to have that? I thought that "mapping.fromJS" will create the 'Data' structure for me, based on the complex mode that is in my WebAPI reply.

Comment: WAIT WAIT WAIT!!! That worked!!! You are a beautiful man! Wow... Well, I'm getting impreoved results. The changes are going back to the server! Wow! I'll fix it up as it's all hacked and see if I'm done. THANK YOU.

Comment: @Craig I changed to not use this `Data` class.  Also changed the `self.loadData` and added `<!-- ko if: Data() != null -->` to avoid exception because `Description` in `Data().Description` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Your input field could be this:

```
<div data-bind="with: Data">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Template Name" data-bind="value: Description">
 </div>
```

I prefer using `with` as its cleaner and should stop the confusion and issues you were having.

The reason that error is there is because the html is already bound before the data is loaded. So either don't apply bindings until the data is loaded:

```
$.get("/api/PlateTemplate/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
        self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
        ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById("container"));
    });
```

Or wrap the template with an `if`, therefore it won't give you this error as Data is undefined originally.

```
self.Data = ko.observable(); // undefined

<!-- ko if: Data -->
<div data-bind="with: Data">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Template Name" data-bind="value: Description">
 </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Also if you know what the data model is gonna be, you could default data to this.

```
self.Data = ko.observable(new Data());
```

Apply Bindings Method:

```
var viewModel = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel = new PlateTemplateViewModel();
    viewModel.loadData();
});
```

Comment: In my document.Ready - should I remove the ko.ApplyBinding? And move it to my loadData function? If so, it never gets run.

Comment: in your documentReady replace ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("container")); with viewModel.loadData();

Comment: Damn,.. I have tried that and get the same results. Posts back the original model I loaded. Not the updated one. this.Data seems to not be updated when I edit fields.

Comment: Just to confirm, on my input boxes, I am binding like this:  data-bind="value: Data().Description()"  .... Data is displayed, but not posted back.

Comment: Can you get a fiddle going for it? I don't see an issue in getting it too work. But i believe instead of doing self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)), it should be self.Data(new PlateTemplateData(data)) instead of using there mapping, will give you more control, and then like i said in question instead of self.Data = ko.observable() ie undefined you would have self.Data = ko.observable(new PlateTemplateData()) ie an empty but bound form